# Jquery second change not firing

Tags: jquery, selector, event-listener

I'm having an issue where my second event listener does not seem to be properly performing. I am looking to update the text in my div descrip with each selection from a dropdown, but the text only gets changed for the first change. After that, despite the dropdown menus properly firing, the text is not updated at any point with any of the changes. I feel as though it must be a problem with the selectors, but I'm not 100% certain and I'm very new to Jquery. I have attached the fiddle below showing my issue. Any help is greatly appreciated. 
https://jsfiddle.net/042swvdx/4/

HTML:

```
<h1 style='text-align:center;'>Accu Tab Submittal Builder</h1>
<br>
<div style='text-align:center;'>

    <div id='descrip'>
        <p>Please select a chlorinator model</p>
    </div>
    <form id='first'>
        <select>
            <option selected disabled>Chlorinator Models</option>
            <option value='Accu-tab 2075'>Accu-Tab 2075</option>
            <option value='Accu-tab 2150'>Accu-Tab 2150</option>
            <option value='Accu-tab 2300'>Accu-Tab 2300</option>
            <option value='Accu-tab 2600'>Accu-Tab 2600</option>
            <option value='POWER PRO 3075'>3075 Power Pro</option>
            <option value='POWER PRO 3150'>3150 Power Pro</option>
            <option value='POWER PRO 3530'>3530 Power Pro</option>
            <option value='POWER PRO 30600'>30600 Power Pro</option>
            <option value='POWER PRO 361000'>361000 Power Pro</option>
            <option value='POWER PRO 481200'>481200 Power Pro</option>
        </select>

        <select id='second' style="display:none;">
            <option selected disabled>Select Flow</option>
            <option value='Gravity'>Gravity</option>
            <option value='Standard'>Standard</option>
        </select>

        <select id='third' style='display: none;'>
            <option value='1 PH'>1 Phase</option>
            <option value='3 PH'>3 Phase</option>
        </select>

        <select id='fourth' style="display:none;">
            <option disabled selected>Control Type</option>
            <option>No Control</option>
            <option>WEG</option>
            <option>VFD</option>
        </select>
        <button style='display: none'>Submit</button>
```

JQUERY:

```
$("#first").change(function() {
    $("#descrip").html("<p>Please select the flow type for this system.</p>");
    $("#second").show();
});

$("#second").change(function() {
    $("#descrip").html('<p>Please select the phase of the motor for this unit.</p>');
    $("#third").show();
});

$("#third").change(function() {
    $("#descrip").html("<p>Please select units control type.</p>");
    $("#fourth").show();
});

$("#fourth").change(function() {
    $("#descrip").html("");
    $("button").show();
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is not that the second event is not firing. Your first 'change' event is set to your `<form id='first'>` tag. This means that each time something inside your form tag gets changed by the user it will fire a new event. I persume that you would like to set your first event to the first select element. I changed the id of your first select like this:

```
<form> <select id='first'>
```

Look [here](https://jsfiddle.net/042swvdx/5/) for the working Version at JSFiddle.